# Windows 7/8, Direct3D9, 10, and 11 - Effects / Shaders

Tags: c#, windows-8, directx, directx-9, directx-10

Currently, i'm developing an app for the Windows 8 Store, Windows 8 Desktop and also Windows 7. The App should run smoothly on a Tablet and also on a "normal" Windows 7/8 Device. So, i got a tablet from my work and installed Windows 8 on it, just to realize, that the creepy Intel Graphics Media Accellerator (600) only supports DirectX 9.0c.

So, i tried for hours now to get my DirectX10/11 Effects/Shaders working on DirectX9, but nothing seems to work.. a Test with NVidia's FxComposer shows me, that DirectX9 Effects run good.

I'm programming with SharpDX / C#, and the technique10's and technique11's both are valid (MyTechnique.IsValid == true). To load the effect, i use theese lines of code:

```
var EffectByteCode  = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("DirectX/Shaders/"+FxFile, "fx_5_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
var Effect      = new Effect(GraphicsProvider.Device, EffectByteCode, EffectFlags.None);
mEffect             = FxEffect;
mTechnique11            = mEffect.GetTechniqueByName("main_11"); //works
mTechnique10            = mEffect.GetTechniqueByName("main_10"); //works
mTechnique9             = mEffect.GetTechniqueByName("main_9"); //doesn't work
```

I pasted the effect source code here: http://pastebin.com/KPxBN1DD.. excluded "main_11" and "main_10", in my tests, i commented them out, so i just removed those comment blocks.. i think dx9 should understand this very simple code..

So my final questions are:
 - Is the parameter "fx_5_0" valid for loading technique, technique10 and technique11?
 - Is my shader code correct? Or have i done something terribly wrong?
 - Do i have to specify any other/additional information/functions/parameters for loading DX9 technique's?
 - Maybe its a bug of SharpDX? I will take look on the code for this now i think..

Edit: Tried to make the question(s) a bit clearer..

Comment: To ask a good question you need to narrow your focus down to a specific item.  Is your question: how do I get Dx9 effects working in a certain situation?  If so, then focus your post on that.

Comment: You sure the Technique Name for DirectX 9.0c is "main_9" why do you even need that technique, if its not 10 or 11, then by elmination its 9.

Comment: @mydogisbox: Its more a general dx9 effect question - the question is, why doesn't the technique show up as "IsValid = true". And i gave you the source code of what i'm exactly doing, and pointed out, that technique's for dx10 and dx11 are showing up as "IsValid = true" and FxComposer also can execute and compile the code - so i must do anything really wrong, but doesn't know why..

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, i'm shure, because GetTechniqueByName try's to load a technique which is called "main_9" - and in my code, i definied the "main_9". And, yes, i simply could name it "main", but the name doesn't really matter, i think.. and i liked to define a "fallback" technique, which doesn't has geometry shaders and stuff, to support systems which only have Dx9 (or half Dx10 support, like Intel GMA 600 on my tablet..).. i hope, i didn't understand your answer wrong o_o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legacy Effect framework is not supported on Windows 8 Metro (because D3DCompiler_xx.dll is not supported), so you should better work with another solution. Also, Effect is deprecated by Microsoft and no longer supported.

The old Direct3D9 technique(compiled with vs_2_0 or ps_2_0) are not stored in FX files compiled with fx_5_0 (just check the output of fxc.exe compiler and you won't see them).

You have to use vs_4_0_level_9_x or ps_4_0_level_9_x in order to compile them for 9.x down level hardware support using technique10/11 syntax. Also, if all your original shaders could work with vs_4_0_level_9_x and you don't have any specific optimized version for 10.0 or 11.1, then you wouldn't have to compile a main_10 or main_11, as level_9_x shaders are working on any hardware from 9.x to 11.x.

You can probably have a look at SharpDX.Toolkit, not yet official, but It is supporting an Effect framework (with some XNA stock effects like BasicEffect or SpriteBatch). A beta of the toolkit will be available later this month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But isn't D3dCompiler also used for generic shaders? So i can't event use normal shaders, where i specify/load entry points like "PS", "VS",.. in a Metro App? And, thank you, i will have a look at SharpDX.Toolkit : Sounds good!

Comment: d3dcompiler allows to compile a plain HLSL file to a binary shader. When you create a Direct3D11 Shader object (VertexShader, PixelShader...etc.), you just pass this binary data without using d3dcompiler. So you can program the whole Direct3D11 API without having to use D3DCompiler. But one of the annoying thing is that when you don't have D3DCompiler, you don't have anymore ShaderReflection that is usually used to query a shader bytecode and ask for information about it. This is where SharpDX.Toolkit is also useful, as it stores reflection data in a custom format as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the SV_TARGET semantic with COLOR0. I've never seen SV_TARGET semantic in D3D9 shaders so far.

Comment: Good suggestion, but also doesn't make a difference =/